# How can i prevent that users browse my site with a specific browser?

Tags: cross-browser

Thans for your help.

Please let me know that:

How can i prevent that users browse my site with a specific browser?

Thanks
Ali

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that...?

Comment: Have you considered not arbitrarily restricting users? Just a thought.

Comment: I have actually come across commercial websites that did this. browser X only? Really... never mind I'll just click over to the competition that was kind enough to support the browser of my choice rather than force me to down load a browser to view your site.

Comment: Because some browsers like opera make easy to download mp3 by users.

Comment: I've heard using computers also makes it easy to download mp3s.  Better block those.  Also smart phones.

Comment: Use a proprietary ActiveX that will only work with IE? That is the only thing I can think of. 
Any user can download it. It is in the cache. In fact, trying to prevent it will likely make power users more agitated, and then they will make sure to get it other ways. See video download helper for firefox for example.

Comment: Here's a thought.  If you don't want users to have the ability to download an MP3, then don't put the MP3 on the server..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Browsers will supply a user-agent header with each HTTP request, and you can use that to determine which browser a request says it is from.  But the browser is often lying.  In part because of developers (like you?) who try to restrict their sites to certain browsers, many browsers and users "spoof" the user-agent string, or include names of browsers they are not within that string.

If your specific concern is preventing Javascript compatibility problems, a much better approach is checking for a given piece of functionality (in Javascript) before using that functionality.  This will work across browser types.

Answer (score 1):

Using i.e. jQuery, you could detect user's browser and redirect him to 'Sorry, this browser is not supported' page as follow:

```
if($.browser.msie)
{
  document.location.href = "sorry.html";
}
```

This will work as long as user has javascript turned on. But this is not appropriate solution... good website should work correctly on all major browsers.